# Pragma no cache driving me crazy - Internet explorer

Tags: php, magento, internet-explorer, caching, pragma

I'm managing a website with Magento but Magento isn't the problem.

When i'm using internet explorer 11 (only IE), all is caching even if cart page. So we don't have the good version of the page. When i'm adding an item to the cart and go to the cart page, i have the last version.

The only solution i've found is to use meta pragma no cache but it's not OK with HTML5.

I tried to use headers in HTACCES and magento is using PHP header but no...

How we can definitively and in a proper way tell to IE to stop caching a webpage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Magento and I'm certain it is able to handle this directly. Furthermore, I believe there are already answers regarding cache settings.

Anyway, the Pragma header is HTTP/1.0 whereas the HTTP/1.1 header is Cache-Control

`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`

Use the header above if you try to solve your problem with a .htaccess file. I think IE should handle it properly.

Comment: You can't imagine all the topics i red in order to try to stop this. Magento already sends header pragma in PHP so it's ok. And with HTACCESS i tried a lot of solutions but anyone works. It this possible that a particular server's configuration or a server's app creates this problem ?

Comment: @MathieuBaefcop Pragma is an old header and hasn't to be honered by newer browsers. Have you tried Cache-Control? Furthermore, can you post the .htaccess content to ensure it is all set correct. have you verified that the headers are correctly sent to the client?

Comment: @MathieuBaefcop Furthermore, you should be carefull to not set those headers for static content like pictures etc. And regarding that topic i might have found your solution of a proper configuration here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12178558/6100314)